# how to override style in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using  [flutter_fortune_wheel](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fortune_wheel)  for make roulette game in flutter

In Documentation there I can customize it but.

When I use `FortuneWheel` like this

```
FortuneWheel(
  selected: Stream.value(0),
  items: [
    FortuneItem(
      child: Text('A'),
      style: FortuneItemStyle(
        color: Colors.red, // <-- custom circle slice fill color
        borderColor: Colors.green, // <-- custom circle slice stroke color
        borderWidth: 3, // <-- custom circle slice stroke width
      ),
    ),
    FortuneItem(child: Text('B')),
  ],
)
```

Colors is working fine

But in `FortuneBar` not working

```
FortuneBar(
  // using alternating item styles on a fortune bar
  styleStrategy: AlternatingStyleStrategy(),
  selected: Stream.value(0),
  items: [
    FortuneItem(
      child: Text('A'),
      style: FortuneItemStyle(
        color: Colors.red, // <-- custom circle slice fill color
        borderColor: Colors.green, // <-- custom circle slice stroke color
        borderWidth: 3, // <-- custom circle slice stroke width
      ),
    ),
    FortuneItem(child: Text('B')),
  ],
)
```

and also there is no error

so question in how can I override background color of `FortuneItem` for `FortuneBar`

thank you

Comment: Tell FortuneBar  to use `styleStrategy: UniformStyleStrategy()`,

Comment: yes i can set `styleStrategy: UniformStyleStrategy()` inside `FortuneBar` widget but it change's background color to complete skyblue not changing set color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found it](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_fortune_wheel/latest/flutter_fortune_wheel/UniformStyleStrategy/UniformStyleStrategy.html):

```
  styleStrategy: UniformStyleStrategy(
                   color: Colors.red, / 
                    borderColor: Colors.green,  
                    borderWidth: 3,
                 ),
```

Or in ThemeData,`primarySwatch: Colors.green,`

Here is full example

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_fortune_wheel/flutter_fortune_wheel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 StreamController<int> selected = StreamController<int>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    selected.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
     final items = <String>[
      'Grogu',
      'Mace Windu',
      'Obi-Wan Kenobi',
      'Han Solo',
      'Luke Skywalker',
      'Darth Vader',
      'Yoda',
      'Ahsoka Tano',
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Fortune Wheel'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selected.add(
              Fortune.randomInt(0, items.length),
            );
          });
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FortuneBar(
                selected: selected.stream,
                styleStrategy: UniformStyleStrategy(
                   color: Colors.red, // <-- custom circle slice fill color
                    borderColor: Colors.green, // <-- custom circle slice stroke color
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end
                ),
                items: [
                  for (var it in items) FortuneItem(child: Text(it)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],    ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the reply but I want to change `FortuneItem` instead of full color its mean i want to add style here `FortuneItem(child: Text(it))` not in FortuneBar because Roulete have 3 colors `black, green, white`

Comment: then its not possible in flutterbar only in wheel, maybe you need to fork that package and make changes

Comment: Yes thats what i did now thank you